# 1 FloatingActionButton for 2 different logos

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to be able to change dynamically the logo of the fab "It will be my favorite button". When I click on it the logo should switch between 1 to another (like on and off).

For example when you click on it the stars becoming yellow.

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the simulator with my mouse on the Fab and on the right screen I'm on the onclicklistener with the 2 different drawable I want to be dynamically changeable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write below outside any method.

```
boolean isClicked  = false;
```

Inside click Listener code

```
 {
  isClicked = !isClicked;
 if(isClicked)
    mFavoriteFab.setImageResource(R.drawable.liked);
else
    mFavoriteFab.setImageResource(R.drawable.unliked);
 }
```

Comment: No need to use a boolean. You can use the FAV's TAG property to store this simple state.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini. You are right. That is also one way to accomplish  that.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Interesting, how would you do that ? I need more precise information cause I'm still on the learning process.

Comment: @SimpleCoder 's solution is fine, but I think your underlying problem is different. I see you want to indicate whether something is favorite or not, the view (where the Fab is floating), which is your Activity/Fragment shouldn't need to decide what drawable to use; instead they should be told by your business logic (whether this is a Presenter, ViewModel or whatever, is irrelevant). In any case, not to confuse you any further for now, I'll post an alternative answer just so you see what I mean (wouldn't fit comfortably here).

Answer (score 2):

I believe SimpleCoder's solution is appropriate. An alternative, if you want to rely on one less boolean (but one more business rule hidden in your View), you can use the `tag` property of any `View` to store something.

Pseudo-Code:

```
if (mFavoriteFab.tag == null) {
    mFavoriteFab.tag = "" // no longer null
    // set drawable 1   


} else {
    mFavoriteFab.tag = null
    // set drawable 1
}
```

You're not saving much memory and it's not necessarily more clear (I insist this "decision" (the `if`) doesn't belong in your Activity/Fragment/View code, but still, for something as simple as this, you can get away with any similar approach.